# How to end the CQL shell?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cqlsh

I am learning Cassandra right now.The problem is here

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> q
   ... quit
   ... HELP
   ... !
   ... EXIT
   ... 
   ... quit
   ... !
   ... EXIT
   ...
```

How can I quit the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<control-c>exit<enter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, what's happening above, is that cqlsh thinks that you're entering a multi-line command:

```
aploetz@cqlsh> q
   ... quit
   ... EXIT
   ... exit
   ... ;
Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'q'
aploetz@cqlsh>
```

Note that when I provide a semi colon (`;`) it gets me back to the cqlsh command prompt.  Then `exit` will work fine (even without a semicolon).

```
aploetz@cqlsh> exit
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Official page also writes the exit command...

Answer (score -1):

I just registred for this answer)
I find in docs, use command EXIT for it)
Just uppercase